# How to replace empty cells of a particular column in a list with a character in R

Tags: r, string, list, replace

I have a list with around 100 data frames and want to replace the empty cells in a particular column (named Event) of all the data frames in the list with a character. I first tried the following code,

```
lapply(my_list, function(x) replace(x,is.na(x),"No_Event"))
```

The above code replaces all the NA into '"No_Event". But I want the replacement of the empty cells in a specific column. Also not sure how to represent the blank cells in the code. The following " " doesn't work.

Then I tried,

```
lapply(my_list, function(x) transform(x, Event = chartr(" ", 'No_Event', Event))
```

I understand that the above code replaces a particular letter with the specified character, but not sure how to transform the empty/blank cells of the specific column with a character. Besides, I also tried some other codes, which produce errors. Apologies if the question is very basic and the approach that I followed is wrong.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a reproducible example (`R Version 4.1.0`)

```
library(tidyverse)

my_list <- list(
  data.frame(a = 1:5, Event = c(6, "", "", 9, ""), c = 11:15), 
  data.frame(a = 1:5, Event = c("", "", "", 8, 9), c = 16:20)
)

lapply(my_list, FUN = \(x) {
  x |> mutate(Event = case_when(Event == "" ~ "No event", TRUE ~ Event))
})
```

For earlier R versions:

```
lapply(my_list, FUN = function(x) {
  x %>% mutate(Event = case_when(Event == "" ~ "No event", TRUE ~ Event))
})
```

Comment: Many thanks for your reply. I tried. But it returns the following error, "Error: must be a character vector, not a `factor` object". I check my list and the particular column is in character format.

Comment: Some/all `Event` columns in your data are factors and need to be converted to character before evaluation. Use this: `lapply(my_list, FUN = \(x) {
  x |> mutate(
    Event = as.character(Event), 
    Event = case_when(Event == "" ~ "No event", TRUE ~ Event)
    )
})`

Comment: Ya Right. Yes, It worked. Thanks a lot :-)